# Gem loads in irb but not console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle

This one is driving me nuts.  I can load a gem via irb:

```
steve@server:/var/www/listings$ irb
irb(main):001:0> Gem.path
=> ["/home/steve/.gem/ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1"]
irb(main):002:0> require 'nokogiri'
=> true
```

But I can't load it through the rails console:

```
irb(main):001:0> Gem.path
=> ["/home/steve/.gem/ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1"]
irb(main):002:0> require 'nokogiri'
=> false
```

The gem (nokogiri) is installed

```
steve@server:/var/www/listings$ gem which nokogiri
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.3.1/lib/nokogiri.rb
```

And bundle agrees

```
steve@server:/var/www/listings$ bundle show nokogiri
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.3.1
```

But, of course, rake spec fails with

```
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:304:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- Nokogiri (LoadError)
```

Other environment info:

```
steve@server:/var/www/listings$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
steve@server:/var/www/listings$ rails --version
Rails 3.0.1
steve@server:/var/www/listings$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/ruby/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/ruby/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/steve/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Any suggestions??

**Edit**

By the way, Nokogiri is in the Gemfile and bundle install completes without complaint.

This is a project I'm moving from windows to Ubuntu.   On windows it's working fine (oddly enough!) so I'm pretty sure it's an environment thing.

Comment: It sure is, see answer below..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

require returns false if that file has already been loaded. Try it out in your irb session by performing the require statement twice in a row. The second one will return false:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'nokogiri'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'nokogiri'
=> false
```

If the file could not be found, require will raise a LoadError instead.

Your exception message (No such file to load -- Nokogiri), makes it seem like something is requiring 'Nokogiri' instead of 'nokogiri', which might be a problem on a case-sensitive operating system.

Comment: My guess is also a case problem that “disappears” in the case-insensitive Windows environment. I suggest the OP try `grep -FR Nokogiri .` (from the root of the application) to try to find the uppercase mention(s).

Comment: Thank you both, it was a casing problem.. that's taking some getting used to.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you require it in your Gemfile and do a bundle install.

Edit - Try requiring rubygems, then nokogiri.

Comment: Gemfile already contains an entry for gem 'nokogiri' and bundle install completes successfully.

Comment: The edit part helped when I was trying to load gem via irb (without any rails project)