# How to require ActiveRecord In IRB

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems, require, irb

I would like to load the ActiveRecord gem in my IRB session, but the following is not working:

```
require 'activerecord'
2.4.1 :004 > require 'activerecord'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- activerecord
    from /Users/robskrob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/robskrob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/robskrob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

and Neither is this one:

```
2.4.1 :018 > require 'activerecord-5.1.2'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- activerecord-5.1.2
    from /Users/robskrob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/robskrob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
    from (irb):18
    from /Users/robskrob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

This is my Gem path in irb:

```
        2.4.1 :012 > Gem.path
     => [
          "/Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1", 
          "/Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global
        ]
```

and here are my active record gems:

```
ls /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activere
activerecord-4.2.10/   activerecord-5.1.2/    activerecord-5.1.4/    activerecord-5.1.6/
activerecord-5.0.0.1/  activerecord-5.1.3/    activerecord-5.1.5/    activeresource-5.0.0/
```

How do I load one of those ActiveRecord gems into my IRB session?

I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694428/requiring-activerecord-on-irb-ruby-no-rails?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115653/gem-loads-in-irb-but-not-console?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but I could not source a solution from either the questions or the answers.

Comment: Are you using [Bundler](http://bundler.io)?

Comment: @tadman yes I am using bundler to install gems.

Comment: You'll need to `require 'bundler/setup'` first, too, to ensure your Bundler environment is loaded before attempting to require any gem dependencies.

Comment: @tadman that's a very interesting point. Nevertheless, I was able to successfully load `activerecord` with `require('active_record')` and without `require 'bundler/setup` as you suggested. How was it that I did not need to `require 'bundler/setup` before `require('active_record')`? Perhaps I am misunderstanding your suggestion.

Comment: If you look at $LOADED_FEATURES immediately after starting irb you’ll see that some RubyGems code has already been loaded.

Comment: The `bundler/setup` part is to ensure you're using the correct ActiveRecord version as specified in your `Gemfile` and not just whatever version happens to be installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `require('active_record')`

If you take a look at the gem Github repo the actual file name is active_record.rb so the above code should work.

https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib

Comment: This was renamed in around ActiveRecord 3.0, wasn't it?

Comment: I don't' really know to be quite honest. So in irb what require does is looks for any gems pass in  as a parameter and if it's not able to find the gem it will through the error "LoadError: cannot load such file --"