# activerecord gem shows up in gem list but get file not found error when trying to load

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems

I want to pull some data from the major league baseball gameday API and insert into a local MySQL database using ruby.

I'm trying to use activerecord gem to insert data into MySQL DB but I can't get the activerecord gem to load.

I try to load the activerecord gem in irb but get error:

```
    irb(main):008:0> require 'activerecord'
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        3: from (irb):8
        2: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
LoadError (cannot load such file -- activerecord)
```

At first I thought activerecord wasn't installed correctly but when I pull the gem list in terminal it does show up.

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activemodel (5.2.0)
activerecord (5.2.0)
activesupport (5.2.0)
...
```

Any suggestions on what might be wrong greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191222/how-to-require-activerecord-in-irb?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the following solution:

Try this:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'active_record'
```

You'll need the first line to ensure your Bundler environment is loaded before attempting to require gems with dependencies.

If you take a look at the [Github repo](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord) for `activerecord`, the actual file name is `active_record.rb`, which explains the second line.

Comment: Boom! Thank you.